# Any Firefox addon for viewing logfiles?

Tags: firefox, software-rec, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

Has anyone found an add-on that helps when you are viewing log files?

If that doesn't exist is there an add-on that lest me easily toggle word-wrap on text files?

Answer (score 0):

No add-on, but you can set up [word-wrap on text files](http://ttcs.wordpress.com/2008/02/12/how-to-apply-word-wrap-to-text-files-viewed-in-mozilla-firefox/#comment-2551) viewed normally through a tab.

1. Open up your **profile** folder

   - Help > Troubleshooting Information... > Profile Directory > [Open Containing Folder](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles?s=profile)
2. Open the **chrome** folder
3. Edit the **userContent.css** in a text editor

   - If this file does not already exist, you can usually find a file called **userContent-example.css** to copy and rename as above.
4. Include the following line in the file:

   ```
   pre { white-space: pre-wrap; }
   ```
5. Save and restart Firefox.

Now, whenever you view a logfile, which is just a plain text file, it will be wrapped for long lines.

This does have the side-effect of affecting all other sites you may visit that use the `<PRE>` tag when displaying text, so be mindful of that.